# Flutter Slider | How to limit the possible input?

Tags: flutter, slider

How to make the user input value greater than 50 when the range of input is from 1 to 100. If the user inputs anything less than 50 then it won't be counted as an input. User will have to input anything greater than 50 to count it as an input.

Answer (score 1):

Slider has two property min and max . You can use it to define constraint for slider.